# Launch Android settings app through url intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is there a way to launch the Android settings panel from a web app using an url like:
settings://

I've been looking for a comprehensive list of Android intent filter urls for quite sometime but can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using an intent filter, no. But there is a native intent String you **can** use [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html). Something like [`ACTION_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SETTINGS) will probably bring you to the main settings screen, and any one of the other `ACTION_`'s will bring you to more specific panels within the Settings app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would need to be called from a native app right?

Comment: Yes,  you'd have to have some Javascript-to-native interface, which I believe is part of the SDK somewhere. *Edit: [here it is](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript)*

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to launch the Android settings panel from a web app using an url like: settings://

No, sorry.